# Modify Circle using Open Layers 3.7

Tags: openlayers-3

I am upgrading open layers library from 2.13 to 3.7. I am able to draw rectangle or circle but not able to modify them. It is taking rectangle as polygon and when resizing, going out of boundaries.

For circle, couldn't find any option. Please help.

Comment: Are you able to put this on a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, this library is getting used at many places. But here are links from examples:                                                                                       1) http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/draw-features.html - here i am able to draw circle                                                                             2) http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html - not sure how to modify a circle

Answer (score 0):

`ol.interaction.Modify` does not currently support `ol.geom.Circle` geometries. You would have to write your own interaction, or contribute to the ol3 project.

Comment: Any update on this? Where do I even start making my own interaction handler?